# Flutter GetX and AutoRoute: Get.context is null (Get is not initialized properly?)

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, auto-route

I use [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) Flutter framework, but want use use [AutoRoute](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) for navigation. However, if I use AutoRoute, `Get.context` is always `null` in my widgets therefore things such as `Get.width` cause a crash.

Example/steps to reproduce (uses Flutter 3.13.4):

pubspec.yml

```yaml
name: testtest
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

# All versions are locked to the version I used when posting this question
environment:
  sdk: '3.1.2'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: 1.0.2
  get: 4.6.6
  auto_route: 7.8.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: 2.0.0
  auto_route_generator: 7.3.1
  build_runner:

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

lib/main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';
import 'package:testtest/home_screen.dart';

import 'main.gr.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp.router( // (1)
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      routerDelegate: _appRouter.declarativeDelegate(routes: (handler) => [HomeRoute()],), // (2)
      routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(), // (3)
      // home: HomeScreen(), // (4)
    );
  }
}

@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {

  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
    AutoRoute(path: "/HomeRoute", page: HomeRoute.page),
  ];
}
```

home_screen.dart

```dart
import 'package:auto_route/annotations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

@RoutePage()
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double? width = null;
    try {
      width = Get.width;
    }catch(_){}
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child:
        Text(
"""Context: ${Get.context?.toString() ?? "null"}
width: ${width ?? "Error"}
""")
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and don't forget to run code generation for AutoRoute:

```bash
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

---

In the example above, a empty screen with this text will appear:

```
Context: null
width: Error
```

because `Get.context` was `null` and `Get.width` caused and exception.

*However*, If you change `GetMaterialApp.router` to `GetMaterialApp` on line marked (1), comment out lines (2) and (3) and uncomment line (4), AutoRoute will no longer be used and everything works as expected - `Get.context` is no longer `null` and `Get.width` return correct width.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but this might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69168726/navigatorkey-not-found-on-materialapp-router

Comment: I hope the answer helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `Get.context` is null in your `AutoRoute` example is because `GetX` and `AutoRoute` are both navigation libraries, and they conflict with each other when used together.

To fix this, you have two options:

Use GetX for navigation. If you want to use GetX for navigation, then you should remove AutoRoute from your project and use GetX's `Get.to()` and `Get.back()` methods to navigate between screens.
Use AutoRoute for navigation. If you want to use AutoRoute for navigation, then  use AutoRoute's `Router()` to navigate between screens.
If you choose to use AutoRoute for navigation, then you will need to use AutoRoute's own context object to access context-aware services. This is because AutoRoute creates its own widget tree, and GetX's `Get.context` object will not be available within that widget tree.

To access AutoRoute's context object, you can use the `RouteData.context` property. This property is available to all AutoRoute widgets.

Below code is an example of how to use the RouteData.context property to get the screen width in an AutoRoute widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = RouteData.of(context).context?.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Text('Screen width: $width'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!